# How to use a created gem for a specific rails version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I am new to ruby on rails, I just installed my first app.

I created a gem for a specific rails version (not for a specific project) - is there a difference?

```
$ rvm gemset create rails500
  Gemset 'rails500' created.

$ rvm 2.4.1@rails500
$ gem install rails -v 5.0.0
```

Then I wanted to use the gemset to create a new app:

```
$ mkdir blog-app
$ cd blog-app
$ rvm gemset use rails500
  Using ruby-2.4.1 with gemset rails500
$ rails new .
```

This did not create the .ruby-gemset or .ruby-version file for me, but it did create the Gemfile with rails 5.0.0 listed.
So then I created the .ruby-gemset & .ruby-version file:

```
$ echo "ruby-2.4.1" > .ruby-version
$ echo "rails500" > .ruby-gemset
```

I am trying to find out if I did this correctly. Also, do I need the .ruby-gemset file if rails5.0.0 is listed in the Gemfile?

Lastly, I rvm and bundler. Should have I ran bundler install?

Answer (score 0):

`.ruby-gemset` and `.ruby-version` are not created automatically by the rails 5.0.0 generator. What you're doing looks OK.

`.ruby-version` specifies the version of ruby you'd like to use. You can use it with `rvm`, `rbenv` or `chruby` to specify the version of Ruby you want to use in your application.

`.ruby-gemset` is specific to using `rvm`. It's an alternative to using `bundler`. Both `bundler` and rvm `gemsets` accomplish the goal of maintaining an independent list of application dependencies ("gems") separate from system gems. Before `bundler` and rvm `gemsets`, Ruby didn't have a good solution for having separate dependencies per project.

Don't use rvm `gemsets` and `bundler` interchangeably. I recommend getting totally comfortable using one or the other, but not both on the same project. (I should note that I'm not very well versed on `gemsets` so some of my information may be out-of-date. Hopefully someone will correct me if what I've said is inaccurate.)